# how can i install python local project into lambci/lambda docker image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, pip, python-3.6

i work with aws lambda and python 3.6.
i would install a local project named "layerLambdaPython" in the docker image lambci/lambda:python3.6, that is the image fetched when i start to debug an aws lambda function that import layerLambdaPython.

i've tried to create another image using this dockerfile

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.6

COPY layerLambdaPython /layerLambdaPython

#RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install /layerLambdaPython

RUN pip list

RUN rm /var/runtime/awslambda/runtime.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

COPY runtime-mock.py /var/runtime/awslambda/runtime.py

USER sbx_user1051

ENTRYPOINT ["/var/lang/bin/python3.6", "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py"]
```

but i don't know ho to set it as default image to fetch when i debug lambda.
I accept any suggestion to resolve